# How do I send results of sql file to txt including queries run and comments in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I understand I can save my queries etc in an .sql file and run it against a database from the cmd prompt like this:
$ sqlite3 main.db < queries.sql > results.txt

but how can I write my .sql file to print comments or the actual statements themselves so that the results file is self explanatory when viewed?

Comment: `.output` and `.print`?